# Has .Net made obsolete the Chart functionality?

Tags: .net

I am struggling to get good understanding of `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` because [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting?view=netframework-4.8) seems to offer nothing beyond the raw API doc - no overview, no examples, etc. It doesn't even seem to say what types of chart are supported.

Google found me some higher level pages e.g. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd489233(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but all these pages say "We're no longer updating this content regularly."

The last thing I want to do starting a new project is accidentally pick something that's been superceded - is this the case and if so what replaces it for desktop applications in .Net?

Comment: To get a graps of how it works and what types it support see [this repo](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms-datavisualization). It is a port of the .Net Framework version to ease migrations of desktop apps to .Net Core 3. It states that there will be no further developments when it comes to the .Net Core version.

Comment: "We consider the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization deprecated" - in favour of what though @PeterBons? My google searches for .Net forms, etc, turn this up.

Comment: That Charting namespace is only available when Microsoft bought Dandus Charts, https://prologika.com/more-dundas-components-move-to-microsoft/ Microsoft should fully support it on .NET Framework, but not anywhere else. So now you can stick to it or switch to another vendor.